# Should I create a table using HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, html-table

I guess it really depends on my code but if I have the following code, can I just open a HTML tag  and create a table there? I find it easier to create table using HTML than using PHP. Would it be okay to add table in html or must I echo it out in PHP for the following code?

```
     <?php
include_once 'header2.php';

if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
    header ("Location: index.php?display_music_forum=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
  // select query drom the database to insert below in html

    $admin = 1;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM display_music_forum WHERE admin = ?;";

    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
           echo "SQL error";
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $admin)
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0 && $_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
                header("Location: header2.php?display_music_forum=nopermission");
                exit();
            } else {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            }

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>category</th>
<th>Creator</th>
<th>Date Created</th>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Table are created in html and table value fill with php .

Comment: Please explain to us your needs. Why do you need a table here? Do you need to display some data that you stored in an array from a database query?

Comment: Definitely you have to make table in HTML but if you need to use dynamics values in your table then you have to integrate your table with PHP.

Comment: Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not "echo" HTML with PHP. It is better to leave all the text and html outside of PHP.

In your case, in order to have better oraginized code you may do all the php work in the top of your file, and do only the loop (foreach or for) inside the html body.

For exampleQ

```
<?php
include_once 'header2.php';

if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
    header ("Location: index.php?display_music_forum=notlogin");
    exit();
} else {
  // select query drom the database to insert below in html
  ...
  ...
  $results = YOUR DATABASE RESULTS;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>category</th>
<th>Creator</th>
<th>Date Created</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($results as $result) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?=$result['category'];?></td>
<td><?=$result['creator'];?></td>
<td><?=$result['date_created'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have seen some other videos where they have echoed out the table as this: echo "<table border=1>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Category</th>
                      <th>Creator</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      </tr>;
                  "

Comment: It is a bad practise for performance reasons. It will still work and it may be the only way in some cases, but you should avoid it when you can.

Comment: and when should I use while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) instead of just $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc() without the while loop? Someone mentioned that the while loop will loop through each result but if I am doing a forum where the user can keep adding topics, would I use a while loop?

Comment: It depends if you expect one row or a group of results.

Comment: * instead foreach() you may also use while() inside the html.

Comment: So, would it be fair to say that most of the time, I don't need to use the while loop? I am still a bit confused here

Answer (score 0):

You can embed all the html tags inside PHP by using echo.

Here is an example:

```
  $query = $db->rawQuery("SELECT last_modified,version,last_saved_by,comments from tbl_templates WHERE slug = '".$slug."' order by id desc limit 5");

  $i = 1;
  echo '<table class="lastmodified" temp="true" border="1" align="center" width="100%">';
  echo '<tr><td align="center"><h4><b>SL No.</b></h4></td><td align="center"><h4><b>Last version modified</b></h4><td align="center"><h4><b>Last Modified Date and Time</b></h4></td><td align="center"></td><hr><td align="center"><h4><b>Last Saved By</b></h4></td><td align="center"><h4><b>Comments</b></h4></td></tr>';
  foreach ($query as $row){

    echo "<tr><td align='center'><h4>".$i++."</h4></td><td align='center'><h4>{$row['version']}</h4></td><td align='center'><h4>{$row['last_modified']}</h4></td><td><hr></td><td align='center'><h4>{$row['last_saved_by']}</h4></td><td align='center'><h4>{$row['comments']}</h4></td></tr>";
  }
  echo '</table>';
```